# How do you hide/show a sticky footer menu through div tags instead of pixels using JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

First, let me clarify that I am extremely new to this, so I apologize for using the wrong terminology.

I'm looking to recreate Morning Brew's sticky footer opt-in form ([click here for reference](https://www.morningbrew.com/daily/latest)), but the code I'm currently using only tracks pixels. Is there a way I can make it, so it looks for div tags instead?

```js
<script>
  var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos < 4200 && prevScrollpos > 200) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("_form")[0].style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("_form")[0].style.display = "none";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window and get scroll event by this way:

```js
let element = document.getElementById('footer');

  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    let Y = window.scrollY;
    console.log(Y);
    Y > 600 ? element.style.display = 'block' : element.style.display = 'none';
  })
```

```css
body{
    height: 1600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">Element to fix</div>
```

Comment: It's still doing the same thing. /: